# Using Cloudinary in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloudinary

I am working on a Rails project where I used Cloudinary to store images. I got an error while deploying in Heroku. Can I use Cloudinary without a Cloudinary ad-on on Heroku?

Comment: Can you please share more information? How did you implement Cloudinary and what error are you seeing?

In general, it should be possible to use Cloudinary directly and not via the Cloudinary add-on.

Comment: if you use the gem `cloudinary`, maybe you forgot to add a `CLOUDINARY_URL` env variable in heroku

Comment: Hello, @jpheos. I haven't added CLOUDINARY_URL. How can I do that? Do I need to do that even if I provide Cloudinary credentials in a separate file?

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (Must supply cloud_name in tag or in configuration):
2020-10- is the error that I got when I run the deployed project on heroku. It works fine on local machine.

Comment: If you have setup a cloudinary.yml file under the "config" directory of your Rails project then a CLOUDINARY_URL isn't needed. In general, you can add the CLOUDINARY_URL environment variable using Heroku config - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Thank you @AleksandarKostadinov, I finally solved the issue after a long hurdle. I used both cloudinary.yml in the config folder and cloudinary.rb file on the initializer folder. I think that was the issue.